# Stop each loop on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have an anchor with a data attribute (an object of images), on mouseenter I want to loop through these images, then on mouseleave I want this loop to end.

Here's what I have so far, but it seems the full `each` runs, prior to the `shouldRotateImages` variable changing, even with the delay. So I'm a bit lost as to what I can do now.

```
var shouldRotateThumbnails = false;
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#videos-list a', function () {
    shouldRotateThumbnails = true;
    rotateThumbnails($(this));
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '#videos-list a', function () {
    shouldRotateThumbnails = false;
});

function rotateThumbnails(video) {
    var thumbnails = video.data('thumbnails');
    var image = video.find('img');
    $.each(thumbnails, function (k, v) {
        if (!shouldRotateThumbnails) {
            return false;
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            image.attr('src', v);
        }, (300 * k));
    });
}
```

Comment: The code is asynchronous and scheduled to execute later, which will happen no matter what unless you clear the timer. Better to not use a looping construct like `$.each()`, and instead use a `setInterval` that clears itself when it gets to the last image, or when `shouldRotateThumbnails` becomes `false`, whichever comes first.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to do this by using @squint's suggestion.

```
var t;
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#videos-list a', function () {
    var imageKey = 0;
    var thumbnails = $(this).data('thumbnails');
    var image = $(this).find('img');
    t = setInterval(function () {
        image.attr('src', thumbnails[imageKey]);
        imageKey += 1;
        if (imageKey == thumbnails.length) {
            imageKey = 0;
        }
    }, 300);
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#videos-list a', function () {
    clearInterval(t);
    var image = $(this).find('img');
    var thumbnail = $(this).data('original-thumbnail');
    image.attr('src', thumbnail);
});
```